# PHP nuSoap issue when connecting to a .NET server: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: .net, php, soap, nusoap

I am currently working on a SOAP project using PHP.  The script is connecting to a remote .NET service server.  I get a nice response using the *HelloWorld* action the provide, but when the script goes to get any other data using other actions, I get

> *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."*

in a *diffgram* sub array of the *$data array* (see below).

---

Here is the current code, excluding the service URLs and params.

```
<?php

require_once('../lib/nusoap.php');

$options = array(

    # server

    'wsdl'  => false,
    'srvr'  => 'http://test.domain.com/soap/file.asmx',

    'base'  => 'http://sub.domain.com/',
    'act'   => isset($_POST['act'])     ? $_POST['act']     : 'RequestSomething',

    'curl'  => isset($_POST['curl'])    ? $_POST['curl']    : false,
    'char'  => 'UTF-8',

    # proxy

    'host'  => isset($_POST['host'])    ? $_POST['host']    : false,
    'port'  => isset($_POST['port'])    ? $_POST['port']    : false,
    'user'  => isset($_POST['user'])    ? $_POST['user']    : false,
    'pass'  => isset($_POST['pass'])    ? $_POST['pass']    : false,

);

$client = new nusoap_client(

    $options['srvr'],       $options['wsdl'],

    $options['host'],       $options['port'],       $options['user'],       $options['pass']

);

$client->soap_defencoding = $options['char']; 

$client->setUseCurl($options['curl']);

$error = $client->getError();

if($error){

    $debug = htmlspecialchars($client->getDebug(), ENT_QUOTES);

    echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>$error</pre>";

    echo "<h2>Debug</h2><pre>$debug</pre>";

    exit;
}

$params = array(

    'ID' => 123,
);

$send = $params;

$do = $options['base'] . $options['act'];

$data = $client->call($options['act'], $send, $do, $do);    

if($data && $data = (array) $data) {
    echo "<h2>Call data</h2>";
    echo "<pre>" .  print_r($data,true) . "</pre>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php instead of nuSoap.

Comment: I read about it yesterday and tried to use it.  I set the WSDL to false, but couldn't figure out the uri and location parameters needed even though I tried every URL / action combo possible.  This works, it just doesn't grab it right, I guess.

Comment: Here's what I get when I use soapClient.

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://test.dom...' : Premature end of data in tag html line 3 in /folder/file.php:25 Stack trace: #0 /folder/file.php(25): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://test.dom...') #1 {main} thrown in /folder/file.php on line 25

Answer (score 1):

Try [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) (there's a free version) or another similar SOAP test client and make sure that the web service you're consuming actually works as expected.  If it does, **then** worry about your code.